# Adding a number generator to Stack Data Structure using enqueue

Tags: python

I'm new to implementing Queues and need some help here for my practice.

Say, that I'm using enqueue to queue 4 people and I want to add a function to the output to display a random number 'x' from 1 to 10, for 4 times, with the following criteria:

if 'x' is between 1-8, then a name will be added to the queue.
If 'x' is 9 or 10, the program will push 'exit' onto a stack data structure and exit the loop of 4 and display all names on the stack with pop method

Also, with the condition to display the max number of names to be 4 and and minimum to be 0.
Then the results will be displayed for the names that have been added to the queue at the output.

How do I add this in?

```
import random  # We will need this to generate the random number

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.container = []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.size() == 0  

    def enqueue(self, item):
        self.container.append(item)

    def dequeue(self):
        self.container.pop(0)

    def size(self):
        return len(self.container)

    def peek(self) :
        return self.container[0]

q = Queue()
names = ["Same", "Peter", "James", "Daniel"]  # List of possible names
for i in range(0,4):  # for loop 4 times
    rand = random.randint(1, 10)  # Choose a random number
    print("Number Generated:\n" + str(rand))  # Display selected number
    if rand >= 9:  # number is 9 or 10
        break  # Break out of the loop, you can also add other logic here
    else:  # number is less than 9
        q.enqueue(random.choice(names))  # Enqueue a random name
    print(q.items)
```

I am looking to achieve an output like this

```
Number generated: 
8
Number generated: 
3
Number generated: 
2
Number generated: 
10

Completed.

Names of people added to queue:
#3 - James
#1 - Sam
#2 – Peter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to generate a random number and, if the random number meets certain criteria, enqueue a value, else break the loop.  Using your definition of Queue class, the following should perform this operation:

```
import random  # We will need this to generate the random number

q = Queue()  # Initialize the Queue just like you had it
names = ["Same", "Peter", "James", "Daniel"]  # List of possible names
for i in range(0,4):  # for loop 4 times
    rand = random.randint(1, 10)  # Choose a random number
    print("Number Generated:\n" + str(rand))  # Display selected number
    if rand >= 9:  # number is 9 or 10
        break  # Break out of the loop, you can also add other logic here
    else:  # number is less than 9
        q.enqueue(random.choice(names))  # Enqueue a random name
```

Hope this helps with your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help. That was what I'm trying to achieve. How do I print out the values which contain the names at the end? Do I use `print(q.names())` I am trying to use the pop method

Comment: I get an Attribute error when using q.items - `AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'items'` am I doing this correctly? I have edited my codes above so you can take a look.

Comment: Oops, looks like you updated the property to `q.container` - that should be the ticket.  Also, you probably want to pull that out of the `for` loop and make it a standalone line in the script